Looking to create a hierarchical enums
So basically I want to create a enum class that has a main type that will branch out to a sub type and each sub type has a second sub type. The best example for this would be Car. Assume there Honda and a Toyota based on the enum instantiation I want that specific sub type to be limited to, like wise the the second sub typ. for example Car: Honda - Model: Civic - trim: EX, Hybrid. If Toyota - Model: Camry - trim: Sport
I tried creating a enum class for each type such as Car, Model, Trim and Constructing a enum based on that

This is not a thing you can do, but it's not usually a thing you need to do.  What would you do with this that you can't do with three separate enums?

Favour composition over inheritance! Seems that you need a car with properties - brand, model, trim.

The word for this is called a "Sealed Enum".
Java has like 70% support for this, and they (currently) refuse to go the remaining 30% of the way.
So, if you want 100% support for Sealed Enums, that is currently impossible.
But here is how you get the 70%.
sealed interface Alphabet 
    permits 
        Consonant, 
        Vowel 
{}

enum Vowel implements Alphabet {A, E, I, O, U, ;}
enum Consonant implements Alphabet {B, C, D, F, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, P, Q, R, S, T, V, W, X, Y, Z, ;}

Now, Alphabet is NOT an enum. But, you can get some of the benefits of enums.
For example, you still get Exhaustiveness Checking.
final boolean hasAnEEEEESound =
    switch (letter)
    {
        case Vowel.A,
             Consonant.B,
             Consonant.C,
             Consonant.D,
             Vowel.E,
             Consonant.G,
             Vowel.I,
             Consonant.P,
             Consonant.Q,
             Consonant.T,
             Vowel.U,
             Consonant.V,
             Consonant.W,
             Consonant.Y,
             Consonant.Z
             -> true;
        case Consonant.F,
             Consonant.H,
             Consonant.J,
             Consonant.K,
             Consonant.L,
             Consonant.M,
             Consonant.N,
             Vowel.O,
             Consonant.R,
             Consonant.S,
             Consonant.X
             -> false;
    }
    ;

And, to represent your situation, here is your example.
sealed interface Car 
    permits 
        Honda, 
        Toyota 
{}

sealed interface Honda
    implements 
        Car 
    permits 
        Civic, 
        Accord 
{}

sealed interface Toyota 
    implements 
        Car
    permits
        Camry,
        Corolla
{}

Then, you can use it like this.
final int vehicleId =
    switch (car)
    {
        case Civic c -> doSomething(c);
        case Accord a -> doSomethingElse(a);
        case Camry ca -> doSomethingCool(ca);
        case Corolla co -> doSomethingWild(co);
    }
    ;

Then, if you want to split it down further, you can!
Just note, some parts of this are better done using composition, like @LouisWasserman mentioned. I would consider whether some of what you are attempting to model as a Sealed Enum might be better modeled via composition.
